# Stop player from climbing mountains

Tags: game-engine, collision

I want to create an open world FPS game with the BGE. Is there an option with character motion that allows the player to only walk on ground that is (for example) less steep than 10°?

I don't want to place invisible walls next to every mountain in my game.

Comment: I believe you should be able to change the *Step Height* to something lower.

Comment: I think you should explain how your player walks right now.

Comment: my player work with "game logic", i have added a "character motion"...

Comment: I guess you mean you use the motion actuator in "Character motion" mode. - I can't help on that as I never used that.

Answer (score 1):

Under your characters physics settings select *"actor"* as *physics type*. Then there should appear an option **step height**. Increase or decrease this value as you like.